# Read input from windows cmd

Tags: java

How can I get an input from another java program? I have one class that generates a random graph and writes it in the windows cmd console with `System.out.println();`. What I want is this other class to read this output and use it to do some calculations. Both classes are working fine - all I need to know is how to get this output from the first class.

EDIT:
I want this http://pastebin.com/GnsUZVht to read the output that this http://pastebin.com/cgXMCbgb do to put it back in a matrix.

Comment: do you want to read the output from another java program or output done by some other class in the same program? Please specify your question better.

Comment: Please provide an example that illustrates what you want to do. You should include how you expect to run your program.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the question that Nuno wants to write the result of one program out to the terminal, where it can be picked up by a second program.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149828/read-the-output-from-java-exec).

According to that, you can use the [Process Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) , which is used to *create operating system processes*.

The example:

```
ProcessBuilder   ps=new ProcessBuilder("java.exe","-version");

ps.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process pr = ps.start();  

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String line;

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
pr.waitFor();
in.close();
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to just have both classes in the same program and then store the data that is generated from the first class in a variable and then pass those variables as arguments into the next class rather than printing and reading from console.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your want do something like (e.g. in the linux bash)

```
java -jar one.jar | java -jar two.jar | ...
```

The the code in **one.jar** could write to **System.out** whereas the code in **two.jar** then reads from **System.in**.