# How to run a exe file using Java

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class testv1 {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ABC");
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                        .exec("D:\\Program\\Pyinstaller\\Merge\\Test\\dist\\helloworld.exe"); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

I want to run helloworld.exe but it's not working. The program is just printing

```
ABC
DONE
```

I also tried this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class testv1 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ABC");
        try
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\Program\\Pyinstaller\\Merge\\Test\\dist\\helloworld.exe", null, new File("D:\\Program\\Pyinstaller\\Merge\\Test\\dist\\"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

but same output as the previous one.

Comment: You probably have to read the inputstream of the process. Here is an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149828/read-the-output-from-java-exec

Comment: Hi Tom! Are you getting any Runtime errors? If so could you post your stack trace? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a process using a working directory:

exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)

Executes the specified string command in a separate process with the specified environment and working directory.

command is the location of the .exe
envp can be null
dir, is the directory of your .exe
With respect to your code it should be...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\program files\\test\\test.exe", null, new File("c:\\program files\\test\\"));
```

You can use Runtime.exec(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.io.File) where you can set the working directory.

Or else you can use ProcessBuilder as follows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

For reading output from process:

```java
BufferedReader reader = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   builder.append(line);
   builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

Comment: @TomHolland  I have updated the answer for reading the output. Thanks.